# changing the default axis limit

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to limit the value axis in the following example to go from 0 to 1 but it does not seem to take it. Where I am wrong?

```
library(ggplot2)
tmp<- data.frame(testname=c("b","b","a","a","c","c"), variable=c(40,50,40,50,40,50), value=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8, 0.4, 0.8))
tmp
tmp$testname <- factor(tmp$testname, levels=unique(as.character(tmp$testname)))
ggplot(tmp, aes(testname, value)) + geom_point(aes(group=variable, colour= variable), ) +   theme_bw() +  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 1)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: It seems you have an unnecessary comma after the 'aes' in your geom_point. Also, coord_cartesian is implemented by default so you don't have to write that. A simple `+ xlim(0, 1)` does the trick.

Comment: @FrankP. Actually, because he wants to call `coord_flip`, I think he would need to add `+ ylim(0,1)` after removing the `coord_cartesian` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `coord_cartesian` argument and set the limits for the y axis in the `coord_flip` argument with `coord_flip(ylim=c(0,1))`

Using your code, this worked for me:

```
library(ggplot2)
tmp<- data.frame(testname=c("b","b","a","a","c","c"), variable=c(40,50,40,50,40,50), value=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8, 0.4, 0.8))
tmp
tmp$testname <- factor(tmp$testname, levels=unique(as.character(tmp$testname)))
ggplot(tmp, aes(testname, value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(group=variable, colour= variable)) + 
  theme_bw() + coord_flip(ylim=c(0,1))
```